# Combine Languages with Different Region Code

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, multilingual

I'd like to set up a multi-language Joomla site. I don't want to go as far as providing multiple flavors of e.g. English or Portuguese, and I don't want to require users from all English speaking countries to select a country flag or region-specific language Tag (e.g. en-GB) in the language switcher.

Joomla has multi-language support, and you can download language packages - but they are region-specific. Next option was to set up a new content language but the region-neutral options I select are either unavailable or seem to collide with an existing language.

To my understanding, the way localization typically works is that if no region-specific versions are provided, the default 'en' locale should apply to all English-speaking users. How can I achieve this in Joomla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that setting the **URL Language Code** in -Extensions -Languages does the trick.

For instance, in case of English, select one of the English content languages and

1. Change 'Title' and 'Title Native' e.g. to 'English'
2. Pick an available 'Language Tag' that corresponds to an installed language package (en-US, en-GB, ...).
3. Change 'URL Language Code ' to 'en'.
4. Chose one of the existing prefixes for the flag (you could probably create your own, supplying a corresponding image).
5. Leave the rest as is and save.
6. Update your content and menus to use the language - links unfortunately break.

Quickly testing this with Chrome shows that any browser with (any) English as the preferred language gets the English pages. The language switcher shows only language but not region codes - if you don't ask it to show the flags.